# Disable ajax 302 redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, post, sharepoint

I have to make a POST to a Microsoft sign-in service (sharepoint online) which gives back 2 cookies in the response, that can be used for data requests.

However, it comes back with a 302 (Moved Temporarily) message, and it tries to redirect to an invalid page, which makes the ajax request fail and jumps to the "error" part, although the first request has the valid and correct response data in it that I could use.

```
function getFedAuthCookies(token)
{
$.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: token,
    url: "https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0", //loginUrl,  
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",   //'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },   
    // dataType: 'html', // default is OK: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
    success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
        alert("WORKED");
    },
    error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("FAILED");
        reportError(result, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

This is how it looks in the browsers dev console (Network panel)

[image]

How can I stop at the first request, that has the right data and the 302 message?

Comment: This may help - http://techblog.dorogin.com/2013/06/ajax-302-redirects-from-reverse-proxy.html

Comment: I saw this article, but it didn't really help. Since I get the cookies in the request which has a 302 response, I would just like to go on from there. Use those cookies in the future...

Comment: Try the XHR fetch API if wide browser support is not a requirement. Afaik jquery does not support this feature yet.